# MySQL query to select cities under any region given

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database of all regions including cities they are arranged in a tree structure using each ones id as parent region id.

mysql columns are `id` , `parent_region_id` , `region_name`

Structure is like ...

`SELECT region_id, region_type, region_name, parent_region_id, parent_region_name FROM regions_data WHERE parent_region_id = 201`

[image]

Region Types are ....

`Country -> Province (State) -> Multi-Region (within a country) -> Multi-City (Vicinity) -> City`

Only some countries have `Province (State)`, other countries having `Multi-Region (within a country)`.. and these both may or may not have `Multi-City (Vicinity)` level under it.

`US -> California -> Central California -> San Joaquin Valley -> Mojave & Vicinity -> California City`

Like above there will be lot of regions under US and all those regions may have lot of sub regions and cities under those sub regions.

I want a perfect MySQL query which will return all the cities inside the given regions.

Say `Give me all cities under US` OR `Give me all cities under ALASKA STATE`

Is there any MySQL experts here to help me ?

Comment: Mysql can't make recursive query. You should do this by php code or procedure

Comment: @splash58    I dont have much knowledge in procedures.. What kind of procedures ? Can you please elaborate if you can ?

Comment: can you share your table structure?

Comment: i am not sure that anybody here will write a code for you. Try and ask about problem you will be faced

Comment: Post a screenshot of your table. It's tough to understand what your table looks like

Comment: @CY5    Table screenshot attached .. Its the first level records under US .. And those each records have same kind of sub records in the same table.

Comment: What is the region_type for cities? What's the maximum number of levels you have?

Comment: @uri2x region type will be `City` .. Please see the update in question also regarding the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use several JOINs to get through the sub-levels, and then print only those that have the correct `region_type` you're looking for. Assuming that you have a maximum of 6 levels (you can add more if needed pretty easily...):

```
SELECT 
  IF(`t1`.`region_type`='City', `t1`.`region_name`,
    IF(`t2`.`region_type`='City', `t2`.`region_name`,
      IF(`t3`.`region_type`='City', `t3`.`region_name`,
        IF(`t4`.`region_type`='City', `t4`.`region_name`,
          IF(`t5`.`region_type`='City', `t5`.`region_name`, '')
        )
      )
    )
  )
FROM `regions_data`

LEFT JOIN `regions_data` `t1` ON (`t1`.`parent_region_id` = `regions_data`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `regions_data` `t2` ON (`t2`.`parent_region_id` = `t1`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `regions_data` `t3` ON (`t3`.`parent_region_id` = `t2`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `regions_data` `t4` ON (`t4`.`parent_region_id` = `t3`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `regions_data` `t5` ON (`t5`.`parent_region_id` = `t4`.`id`) 

WHERE `regions_data`.`region_name` = 'ALASKA STATE'
```

Comment: Is it possible to select more columns in this query ? Using this we can select only region_name right ?

Comment: Right. That was your question. You can add more columns in the same manner the correct `region_name` is selected.

Comment: suppose there is one column with these records say view_count, and i want to order the result by view_count..How can i achieve that using this query ? is it possible ?

Comment: You use the same structure as above to add a `view_count` column, then add an `ORDER BY 2` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try This in mysql:

```
select @pv:=id as id,region_name, parent_region_id from `your_table_name`
join
(select @pv:=1)tmp
where parent_region_id=@pv
```

I use 1, you can use your desire id

Comment: instead of `1` he can also write `select @pv:=id as id,region_name, parent_region_id from table join (select @pv:=(select id from table where region_name='US'))tmp where parent_region_id=@pv;`

Comment: Yes! he can also use this sub query for finding the id

Comment: I tried this but i am getting only 3 records also they are just one level below US.. Not cities. Here is the result i got -----
202 Alabama 201
6057756 Central Alabama 202
6057762 Oxford (and vicinity) 6057756